# Gone Facebook login button when I use layout_toStartOf and layout_toEndOf in XML

Tags: android, xml, facebook-graph-api, layout

I have an XML file which describes a LoginActivity's layout

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
    android:id="@+id/btnGoogle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/btnLogIn"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/space_under_views"
    android:layout_alignStart="@id/etEmail"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@id/etEmail">
</com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton>

<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/btnFacebook"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/btnGoogle"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/space_under_views"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/btnGoogle"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/btnGoogle"/>
```

The problem is the Facebook button won't show up, unless I delete the following lines:

```
android:layout_toStartOf="@id/btnGoogle"
android:layout_toEndOf="@id/btnGoogle"
```

If I delete those, the button isn't aligned properly. My goal is to set the Facebook login button's size as the Google sign in button's size.
What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered my mistake:

Instead of:

```
android:layout_toStartOf="@id/btnGoogle"
android:layout_toEndOf="@id/btnGoogle"
```

I have to use:

```
android:layout_alignStart="@id/btnGoogle"
android:layout_alignEnd="@id/btnGoogle"
```

This solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

If you give `btnFacebook` as `layout_toStartOf="@id/btnGoogle` and
`layout_toEndOf="@id/btnGoogle`, then think,

where the facebook button should be, at the start of google button or at the end of?

Here you can use

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btnGoogle"
android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/btnGoogle"
```

left or right according to your choice 
and you must have to use `RelativeLayout` as parent layout.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/btnLogIn"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/btnGoogle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@id/etEmail"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/etEmail"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/space_under_views"/>

    <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/btnFacebook"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/space_under_views" />


</LinearLayout>
```

or

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/btnLogIn"
    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/btnGoogle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@id/etEmail"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/etEmail"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/space_under_views" />

    <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/btnFacebook"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/btnGoogle"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/space_under_views" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I prefer using `RelativeLayout`